# How to render pictures of objects in 3D on mobile Safari?

Tags: ios, html, mobile, 3d, mobile-safari

I would like to take a picture of a basketball and render the picture in 3D on mobile Safari.

We need to photograph the object from different angles, but what other steps are needed to accomplish this? Are there any APIs to help with piecing together the different pictures  to form a 3D image?

If it's not possible in mobile Safari, could I accomplish this with a native iPhone app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify a few things here:

- After simply taking pictures of the basketball from different angles you can't "render it in 3D"
- When one says "[render](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendering_%28computer_graphics%29)" it usually means computing the output image based on a [3D model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_model) (which is a mathematical representation of a 3-dimensional object) and/or some algorithm that "renders" the scene
- When you say "3D image" I take you mean you want to have a 2D visual representation of the ball which you can manipulate in 3D space (you don't want a 3D image with actual depth that would be visible to the naked eye) like rotating it

So from what you're saying I think you want to allow the user to rotate the ball "in 3D". This can be simply done by loading the images that you have created and then changing the frames when the user drags his finger across the screen. This can be done in Mobile safari by using touch events, but that's a different topic and you probably will have to ask a separate question about it.

If you want to actually create a 3D model (i.e. a model file, something that can be used by a 3D engine to render the object in 3D space) out of your pictures, you have to use some software that does that (like [3DSOM](http://www.3dsom.com/)). It is completely unrelated to web APIs, mobile-safari, iOS etc.. It doesn't really matter what you use to create your 3D model provided it is supported by your 3D engine you want to use. You can then use libraries like [three.js](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/) to render that object using WebGL or a software renderer (which is more likely to be supported by an iOS device).